# angularjs delete through php

Tags: php, angularjs, sql-delete, page-refresh

I am trying to implement delete functionality in angularjs using php as follows:
delete:
index.html view:

```
<ul>
            <li ng-repeat="r in result">
            {{r.description}}|{{r.name}} | <a href='' ng-click = "edit(r.product_id)">edit</a> | <a href='' ng-click = "delete(r.product_id)">delete</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnid" ng-model="hdn" value="{{r.product_id}}"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

in controller:
delete:

```
//delete
        $scope.delete = function() {
            var elem = angular.element($element);
            var dt = $(elem).serialize();
            //alert($element);
            console.log($(elem).serialize());
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'php/delete.php',
                data: dt,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.rs = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;
            });
        };
```

and in php file: delete.php

```
    <?php
include 'connect.php';
mysql_select_db($database,$con);  
$id = $_POST['hdnid'];
$query = "delete from `product` where `product_id` = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 
echo "You have successfully deleted ";
?>
```

The record gets deleted but the page is not refreshed. I cant see the record deleted until I refresh the page.
Where am I going wrong? how do I refresh the page?

Comment: I'm confused: why do you assign the result of AJAX operation to `$scope.rs` and `$scope.data`, but do not change `$scope.result` in any way?

Comment: i am a complete noob to angularjs so i dodnt know about this. How should i change $scope.result? and what actually is result?

Comment: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/perform-addeditdeleteview-php-using-angular-js  hope it will helpfull

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete it from your scope for it to show up. We don't need to pass the element Id to the scope to get it to work when we click we can capture it with the `this` keyword

```
 $scope.delete = function() {
        //Store the this variable so we can use it in the $http functions
        var that = this
        var elem = angular.element($element);
        var dt = $(elem).serialize();
        //alert($element);
        console.log($(elem).serialize());
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'php/delete.php',
            data: dt,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            // get the elements index and then remove it from the results array

            $scope.result.splice(that.$index, 1);
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.rs = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });
    };
```

Comment: i tried it but still the same. btw what is $index? is it provided by angularjs? i tried it as $scope.products.splice(that.$index, 1); and then $scope.products = data;

Comment: when you use `ng-repeat` it makes an array index for every item it looped for accessible via the items `$index` property.

Comment: Take a loook at this fiddle I made see if you can use anything there.
http://jsfiddle.net/EJ8fW/